# What is the relation of Pyside2 version and Qt version?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I have a question about the specific versions of Pyside2 and Qt5:

I know that Pyside2 is for Qt5, but what is the meaning of Pyside2 verion? The only compatible version of Qt5?

For example, **can Pyside2(version 5.15.2) be used with Qt 5.15.8?**

I haven't try to actually use Pyside2(5.15.2) with Qt5.15.8 yet. I've tried to find the answer on Pyside2 document but found nothing.

Comment: The PySide version is an irrelevant detail. Every PySide build is tied to the specific version of Qt that was used during compilation (which can be found by calling `QtCore.qVersion())`. If you install PySide via pip, it will include its own Qt libraries (usually found in *site-packages/PySide2/Qt*). Platforms that have their own packaging systems (such as Linux) should automatically re-build the PySide packages whenever the Qt packages change. More generally speaking, any library that provides bindings must be linked to its underlying library since it must directly execute its code.

Answer (score 0):

PySide2 is a Python binding for the Qt application framework. The version numbers of PySide2 and Qt can be related, but they don't necessarily have a one-to-one correspondence.

The version number of PySide2 doesn't necessarily indicate the exact version of Qt it's compatible with. It typically represents the version of the PySide2 library itself and the features, bug fixes, and improvements introduced in that version. PySide2 versions are often aligned with Qt versions to some extent, but they can lag behind or introduce their own changes and fixes.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: see [here](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/) _italic_